# how to color background of static control in select-for-folder dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, styles, controls

I mean to color the description dialog that is just below title bar. I succeeded in changing font there but the background is done completely different.

As I read everywhere it is done by capturing WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message, but no one has put a complete code where I should catch this message, this code is as I understand it, I've put it into dialog's callback procedure.

The problem is that the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC never gets called.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlobj.h> //for Shell API, dir dialog
#include <commctrl.h>

int CALLBACK BrowseCallBackProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData) {
  switch(uMsg) {
    case BFFM_INITIALIZED: {
      HWND static_control = NULL;
      char szClassName[_MAX_PATH];
      for (HWND hChild = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_CHILD); hChild != NULL; hChild =  GetNextWindow(hChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))
      {
        if ((GetWindowLong(hChild, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VISIBLE) == 0) continue;
        GetClassName(hChild, szClassName, _countof(szClassName));
        if (!strcmp("Static",szClassName)) {
          static_control = hChild;
          break;
        }
      }
      HFONT hFont = CreateFont (13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Fixedsys"));
      SendMessage(static_control, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
      break;
    }
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
      std::cout << "WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC fired!" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  BROWSEINFOW bi;
  LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
  LPMALLOC pMalloc;
  if (SUCCEEDED (::SHGetMalloc (&pMalloc))) {
    ::ZeroMemory (&bi,sizeof(bi));  
    bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
    bi.lpszTitle = L"ok, now how to make my background... yellow for example ?";
    bi.pszDisplayName = 0;
    bi.pidlRoot = 0;
    bi.ulFlags = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE | BIF_VALIDATE | BIF_USENEWUI | BIF_UAHINT;
    bi.lpfn = BrowseCallBackProc;
    bi.lParam = (LPARAM)L"d:\\";
    pidl = ::SHBrowseForFolderW(&bi);
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the dialog window using the [SetWindowSubclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

In the specified callback function you will receive `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` messages.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentions that the callback procedure you pass to `::SHBrowseForFolder` is only meant to receive events of four types:

- `BFFM_INITIALIZED`
- `BFFM_IUNKNOWN`
- `BFFM_SELCHANGED`
- `BFFM_VALIDATEFAILE`

These events are all unrelated with the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message, which is sent to the window procedure of the parent window.